# Is there a trick to using ST_Intersects in Snowflake with a point and a multipolygon?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geography

I can get ST_Intersects to work with a point and a polygon but not a point and a multipolygon.  Is there an easy way to split the multipolygon into individual polygons and run ST_Intersects on each of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problems intersecting points and multipolygons:

```sql
with a as (
select to_geography('POLYGON((0.0 0.0, 1.0 0.0, 1.0 2.0, 0.0 2.0, 0.0 0.0))') as polygon
union all select to_geography('MULTIPOLYGON(((-124.20 42.00, -120.01 41.99, -121.1 42.01, -124.20 42.0)),  ((0.0 0.0, 1.0 0.0, 1.0 2.0, 0.0 2.0, 0.0 0.0)))')
), b as (
  select to_geography('POINT(0.1 0.1)') point
  union all select to_geography('POINT(3.3 3.3)')
  union all select to_geography('POINT(-124.20 42.00)')
)


select ST_ASWKT(point), ST_ASWKT(polygon), st_intersects(polygon, point) intersects
from a, b
```

The results match exactly what I expected:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My problem was actually caused by what Snowflake thinks is invalid WKT so I need to dig into that. I didn't realize it because I was using TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY instead of TO_GEOGRAPHY.

Comment: Oh, I see - can we explore that "invalid" WKT in another question?

Comment: That would be great since I can't see why it's invalid. I'll post the link shortly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671879/how-do-i-figure-out-why-this-multipolygon-is-invalid-in-snowflake