# How do I figure out why this multipolygon is invalid in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geography

Run this in Snowflake to see that it returns an error.

`with a as ( select to_geography('MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.567446994279891 39.5086159918784 0 0, -75.562456 39.51265 0 0, -75.560317002808333 39.515950000160686 0 0, -75.561742999999993 39.520534 0 0, -75.565546 39.514849999999996 0 0, -75.567446994279891 39.5086159918784 0 0)), ((-75.571759009184774 39.623583997285259 0 0, -75.5712463122867 39.622342955203095 0 0, -75.567694 39.613744 0 0, -75.561934 39.605216 0 0, -75.555869991521988 39.605824005226609 0 0, -75.556733999999992 39.606688 0 0, -75.557502 39.609184 0 0, -75.556878 39.612144 0 0, -75.558446 39.617295999999996 0 0, -75.559614 39.624207999999996 0 0, -75.559102 39.629056 0 0, -75.559446 39.629812 0 0, -75.563328 39.629901 0 0, -75.570798 39.626768 0 0, -75.571299098592291 39.6251077524268 0 0, -75.571759009184774 39.623583997285259 0 0)), ((-75.580363009752176 39.599454999369712 0 0, -75.579291 39.597291999999996 0 0, -75.57916 39.594705 0 0, -75.578007 39.591878 0 0, -75.575426 39.588119999999996 0 0, -75.572118 39.58586 0 0, -75.568646 39.585156 0 0, -75.567689 39.58573 0 0, -75.566625 39.587123 0 0, -75.564604004267125 39.589337004109083 0 0, -75.565823 39.590607999999996 0 0, -75.570774 39.594091 0 0, -75.57287 39.594454 0 0, -75.573681999999991 39.595718 0 0, -75.575760872574207 39.5968808119757 0 0, -75.577721260059008 39.5979773496244 0 0, -75.580363009752176 39.599454999369712 0 0)), ((-75.788595997316847 39.722198993930377 0 0, -75.78857321813 39.7197154361476 0 0, -75.788395 39.700286999999996 0 0, -75.788395 39.700030999999996 0 0, -75.7884665379611 39.6951022248818 0 0, -75.788479176698289 39.6942314495293 0 0, -75.788658 39.681911 0 0, -75.7886469376544 39.681603098048292 0 0, -75.78861599999999 39.680741999999995 0 0, -75.788633391921593 39.6714120622458 0 0, -75.788655907550691 39.659333499406 0 0, -75.788658 39.658211 0 0, -75.788431434671409 39.654318127515495 0 0, -75.788430900679188 39.6543089523983 0 0, -75.7881295637419 39.6491313452212 0 0, -75.7880955854847 39.6485475267544 0 0, -75.787787176812 39.6432484121769 0 0, -75.787541702471188 39.6390306427924 0 0, -75.78754100266589 39.6390186186539 0 0, -75.787449999999993 39.637454999999996 0 0, -75.787202839355288 39.634418454936196 0 0, -75.7871896545333 39.6342564699798 0 0, -75.78689 39.630575 0 0, -75.786216419654011 39.6217124085307 0 0, -75.7854092147263 39.611091659946794 0 0, -75.7850543631961 39.606422723028494 0 0, -75.785053894501687 39.606416556210895 0 0, -75.7843181210525 39.596735662857796 0 0, -75.78384245023949 39.5904770537489 0 0, -75.783842208850487 39.590473877688893 0 0, -75.782823521373089 39.5770705606221 0 0, -75.782460041179007 39.5722880925958 0 0, -75.7824575074535 39.5722547552599 0 0, -75.780785999999992 39.550262 0 0, -75.7796634388864 39.5365036098544 0 0, -75.7795851648761 39.5355442639815 0 0, -75.7795846104508 39.5355374688062 0 0, -75.7795181992453 39.5347235164389 0 0, -75.7762226834811 39.494332849895 0 0, -75.775129622280389 39.4809360180705 0 0, -75.7738556911832 39.465322399495996 0 0, -75.7722345420767 39.4454531900426 0 0, -75.769830558762592 39.415989368484894 0 0, -75.7666931907181 39.377537 0 0, -75.766667 39.377216 0 0, -75.765847374248 39.3671747047822 0 0, -75.7643882360415 39.349298695569395 0 0, -75.7604691694169 39.3012859228405 0 0, -75.7601316135502 39.297150501153595 0 0, -75.760104352373 39.2968165224723 0 0, -75.75 39.297474 0 0, -75.746048 39.297531 0 0, -75.714901 39.299366 0 0, -75.685188 39.297089 0 0, -75.683117 39.294578 0 0, -75.681384999999992 39.293205 0 0, -75.680261 39.292496 0 0, -75.678041999999991 39.292477 0 0, -75.6752 39.290498 0 0, -75.673327 39.291027 0 0, -75.670301999999992 39.290890999999995 0 0, -75.669276 39.291396999999996 0 0, -75.66726899999999 39.290417 0 0, -75.665810999999991 39.290566999999996 0 0, -75.660476 39.291672 0 0, -75.654461 39.291184 0 0, -75.652947 39.291948999999995 0 0, -75.65135 39.291588999999995 0 0, -75.64917899999999 39.293151 0 0, -75.647686 39.29588 0 0, -75.646293 39.29687 0 0, -75.6427 39.299107 0 0, -75.641928 39.300891 0 0, -75.640875 39.301224 0 0, -75.633937 39.301593 0 0, -75.63225 39.301327 0 0, -75.627530999999991 39.304438 0 0, -75.626132 39.30413 0 0, -75.62404699999999 39.306376 0 0, -75.623263999999992 39.308029 0 0, -75.62137899999999 39.308755 0 0, -75.619631 39.310058 0 0, -75.61605999999999 39.309734999999996 0 0, -75.614256 39.308307 0 0, -75.612008 39.308954 0 0, -75.610863 39.309276 0 0, -75.609385 39.308800999999995 0 0, -75.606597999999991 39.30809 0 0, -75.603836 39.311181999999995 0 0, -75.603445999999991 39.309094 0 0, -75.602031 39.30811 0 0, -75.599571 39.308442 0 0, -75.599218 39.309737 0 0, -75.597106 39.309554 0 0, -75.596609 39.309647 0 0, -75.594841 39.309903999999996 0 0, -75.59388899999999 39.308417 0 0, -75.592338 39.309948 0 0, -75.592056 39.311251999999996 0 0, -75.590409 39.311746 0 0, -75.58749499999999 39.311009 0 0, -75.587324999999993 39.309698999999995 0 0, -75.58476499999999 39.308644 0 0, -75.581144999999992 39.311130999999996 0 0, -75.57462 39.313434 0 0, -75.57095799999999 39.318844999999996 0 0, -75.56871599957131 39.323523001317263 0 0, -75.569820001173056 39.326576996779295 0 0, -75.569007 39.328744 0 0, -75.56480599999999 39.331936 0 0, -75.562733999999992 39.332104 0 0, -75.558843 39.333334 0 0, -75.556204999999991 39.335325 0 0, -75.555681007372513 39.33653000312443 0 0, -75.55631799999999 39.337879 0 0, -75.55833399521066 39.339230004872931 0 0, -75.557357995926381 39.341500995668405 0 0, -75.557846 39.342763999999995 0 0, -75.559981999999991 39.343466 0 0, -75.56051899792655 39.345066999353946 0 0, -75.5588 39.346548999999996 0 0, -75.557378 39.349101 0 0, -75.55619 39.348287 0 0, -75.555886 39.346743 0 0, -75.554223 39.345403999999995 0 0, -75.551599 39.345105 0 0, -75.551039996261352 39.345567994418367 0 0, -75.551096 39.349483 0 0, -75.552241999999993 39.350156999999996 0 0, -75.553840999999991 39.349938 0 0, -75.554683007400541 39.351506002990355 0 0, -75.553369 39.35301 0 0, -75.551626 39.35394 0 0, -75.549645 39.353854999999996 0 0, -75.548131 39.352920999999995 0 0, -75.54811 39.351713 0 0, -75.545216 39.350763 0 0, -75.544056 39.351363 0 0, -75.543263 39.353235999999995 0 0, -75.541586 39.354366 0 0, -75.539867 39.353887 0 0, -75.53899 39.351954 0 0, -75.535849 39.350617 0 0, -75.534483994047335 39.351388997582582 0 0, -75.53427799305544 39.353332004157252 0 0, -75.531914 39.354594999999996 0 0, -75.528696 39.353429999999996 0 0, -75.527258995814222 39.354675001898435 0 0, -75.528673 39.356781999999995 0 0, -75.52845300020698 39.358305006725651 0 0, -75.525877 39.359642 0 0, -75.523254 39.359711999999995 0 0, -75.521419999999992 39.358607 0 0, -75.519628 39.360065999999996 0 0, -75.516897 39.360988 0 0, -75.515975 39.364363 0 0, -75.51237208219473 39.365656144406771 0 0, -75.512996 39.366153 0 0, -75.515796999999992 39.378347 0 0, -75.52126299999999 39.381654 0 0, -75.521682 39.387871 0 0, -75.523583 39.391583 0 0, -75.535977 39.409383999999996 0 0, -75.538512 39.416502 0 0, -75.555889999999991 39.430351 0 0, -75.571829994645924 39.438896995945825 0 0, -75.5714550448173 39.4404895611251 0 0, -75.5709849993434 39.442485993390129 0 0, -75.573077 39.445373 0 0, -75.578914 39.44788 0 0, -75.5795930686755 39.4494326149262 0 0, -75.580185 39.450786 0 0, -75.589439 39.460812 0 0, -75.589901 39.462022 0 0, -75.592328999999992 39.467577999999996 0 0, -75.593068 39.477996 0 0, -75.593068000877849 39.47918599762091 0 0, -75.587813999749756 39.49032700194055 0 0, -75.587729 39.495369 0 0, -75.587729 39.4957407450199 0 0, -75.587728998315711 39.4963530034779 0 0, -75.586554401533689 39.497688711813 0 0, -75.581140859129292 39.5038448006784 0 0, -75.576436 39.509195 0 0, -75.574502999999993 39.512516999999995 0 0, -75.5728617838115 39.5160342206675 0 0, -75.572364001474554 39.5171009984447 0 0, -75.570362 39.527223 0 0, -75.569418 39.539124 0 0, -75.569358999999992 39.540589 0 0, -75.565636001056717 39.558509006016514 0 0, -75.564649 39.559922 0 0, -75.5641182880885 39.5606837276848 0 0, -75.563034004787326 39.562239998169261 0 0, -75.570782999999992 39.56728 0 0, -75.571598999999992 39.567727999999995 0 0, -75.586016 39.578448 0 0, -75.586608 39.57888 0 0, -75.58702738490949 39.5798547865464 0 0, -75.58720000000001 39.580256 0 0, -75.587744 39.580672 0 0, -75.591984 39.583248 0 0, -75.592224 39.583568 0 0, -75.597173322751 39.5877820945208 0 0, -75.598747 39.589121999999996 0 0, -75.600785536192 39.5890537256847 0 0, -75.603584 39.58896 0 0, -75.60464 39.58992 0 0, -75.611873 39.597408 0 0, -75.611905 39.597567999999995 0 0, -75.613792996204168 39.606191997215134 0 0, -75.613473001357889 39.606832002184781 0 0, -75.613476995906737 39.606860998404279 0 0, -75.6134736873228 39.606868426370596 0 0, -75.613233 39.607408 0 0, -75.611343991850447 39.610182999893205 0 0, -75.61366500749152 39.612559994452383 0 0, -75.613344994092387 39.613056004804442 0 0, -75.614273 39.61464 0 0, -75.614929004901924 39.615951994615266 0 0, -75.614065 39.61832 0 0, -75.613377 39.620287999999995 0 0, -75.613153 39.62096 0 0, -75.611969 39.621967999999995 0 0, -75.6004949488643 39.6353936845212 0 0, -75.5917467759147 39.6456298433782 0 0, -75.587147 39.651012 0 0, -75.5830124717269 39.6522635452232 0 0, -75.569037 39.656493999999995 0 0, -75.562246 39.656712 0 0, -75.5613567608041 39.6577726838033 0 0, -75.5568448905546 39.6631544390364 0 0, -75.5565726400012 39.663479179279292 0 0, -75.5537715895688 39.666820269999704 0 0, -75.5508077933438 39.6703554837718 0 0, -75.550803870881907 39.670360162481195 0 0, -75.5507962726737 39.670369225617904 0 0, -75.5349831512427 39.689231104242 0 0, -75.5319118207207 39.692894584837696 0 0, -75.52553303088601 39.7005032002623 0 0, -75.512682348589891 39.7158314838503 0 0, -75.509113 39.720089 0 0, -75.4964817737103 39.743315194477894 0 0, -75.490242999999992 39.754787 0 0, -75.4897514259047 39.755503457769095 0 0, -75.4719915820485 39.7813880156216 0 0, -75.4697455653652 39.7846615325088 0 0, -75.4690045587194 39.7857415323977 0 0, -75.468502 39.786474 0 0, -75.446497431828192 39.7963039695592 0 0, -75.4234159950776 39.806614995941658 0 0, -75.428038 39.809211999999995 0 0, -75.4339085190138 39.8117473186932 0 0, -75.4370683549011 39.8131119665163 0 0, -75.437307916589788 39.8132154267429 0 0, -75.449874383721593 39.8186425446778 0 0, -75.45374 39.820312 0 0, -75.454997184031086 39.820770300605005 0 0, -75.4598175446831 39.8225275407136 0 0, -75.4599264483802 39.822567241051004 0 0, -75.463341 39.823812 0 0, -75.463456872955192 39.8238463068355 0 0, -75.472547501842 39.826537795193694 0 0, -75.472677629082384 39.826576322336 0 0, -75.4754890471753 39.8274087068895 0 0, -75.481242 39.829111999999995 0 0, -75.481244921815687 39.8291126972119 0 0, -75.4930772205643 39.831936153535004 0 0, -75.498843 39.833312 0 0, -75.4989861331738 39.833333899718795 0 0, -75.518444 39.836310999999995 0 0, -75.5188176150883 39.836344961758094 0 0, -75.539346 39.838211 0 0, -75.5400582754622 39.838229220042 0 0, -75.5408864120625 39.838250403817796 0 0, -75.5513215785919 39.8385173359007 0 0, -75.570464 39.839006999999995 0 0, -75.5793939947411 39.8385493199286 0 0, -75.579849 39.838526 0 0, -75.5798996512343 39.8385220738603 0 0, -75.5930817368867 39.8375002881084 0 0, -75.593666 39.837455 0 0, -75.59484583814249 39.8372862097586 0 0, -75.595756 39.837156 0 0, -75.617251 39.833999 0 0, -75.634706 39.830163999999996 0 0, -75.634812797602493 39.8301357641688 0 0, -75.641517999999991 39.828362999999996 0 0, -75.662821999999991 39.821149999999996 0 0, -75.667142678086009 39.819267244337 0 0, -75.680794056787789 39.813318592285796 0 0, -75.6815568950873 39.812986181932693 0 0, -75.685991 39.811054 0 0, -75.701208 39.802606 0 0, -75.705787295543 39.7995238880071 0 0, -75.716968999999992 39.791998 0 0, -75.7193345673559 39.7901506045411 0 0, -75.7233991238184 39.7869763794942 0 0, -75.724866264384787 39.785830612575595 0 0, -75.727049 39.784126 0 0, -75.736488999999992 39.775759 0 0, -75.7393235590979 39.77292479948 0 0, -75.7393766862116 39.772871679087004 0 0, -75.744394 39.767855 0 0, -75.751436564661 39.759552050150596 0 0, -75.75306599999999 39.757630999999996 0 0, -75.7544659060403 39.7556311342282 0 0, -75.7592137517567 39.748848497490393 0 0, -75.760101611338087 39.7475801266599 0 0, -75.760346 39.747231 0 0, -75.7658791814134 39.7381059004001 0 0, -75.766058 39.737811 0 0, -75.773786 39.7222 0 0, -75.788595997316847 39.722198993930377 0 0)))') as polygon ),  b as ( select to_geography('POINT(-75.677 39.708)') point   ) select ST_ASWKT(point), ST_ASWKT(polygon), st_intersects(polygon, point) intersects from a, b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that string are the multiple zeroes. If you remove them, then it becomes a valid WKT shape:

```sql
with a as ( 
  select to_geography(
    replace('MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.567446994279891 39.5086159918784 0 0, -75.562456 39.51265 0 0, -75.560317002808333 39.515950000160686 0 0, -75.561742999999993 39.520534 0 0, -75.565546 39.514849999999996 0 0, -75.567446994279891 39.5086159918784 0 0)), ((-75.571759009184774 39.623583997285259 0 0, -75.5712463122867 39.622342955203095 0 0, -75.567694 39.613744 0 0, -75.561934 39.605216 0 0, -75.555869991521988 39.605824005226609 0 0, -75.556733999999992 39.606688 0 0, -75.557502 39.609184 0 0, -75.556878 39.612144 0 0, -75.558446 39.617295999999996 0 0, -75.559614 39.624207999999996 0 0, -75.559102 39.629056 0 0, -75.559446 39.629812 0 0, -75.563328 39.629901 0 0, -75.570798 39.626768 0 0, -75.571299098592291 39.6251077524268 0 0, -75.571759009184774 39.623583997285259 0 0)), ((-75.580363009752176 39.599454999369712 0 0, -75.579291 39.597291999999996 0 0, -75.57916 39.594705 0 0, -75.578007 39.591878 0 0, -75.575426 39.588119999999996 0 0, -75.572118 39.58586 0 0, -75.568646 39.585156 0 0, -75.567689 39.58573 0 0, -75.566625 39.587123 0 0, -75.564604004267125 39.589337004109083 0 0, -75.565823 39.590607999999996 0 0, -75.570774 39.594091 0 0, -75.57287 39.594454 0 0, -75.573681999999991 39.595718 0 0, -75.575760872574207 39.5968808119757 0 0, -75.577721260059008 39.5979773496244 0 0, -75.580363009752176 39.599454999369712 0 0)), ((-75.788595997316847 39.722198993930377 0 0, -75.78857321813 39.7197154361476 0 0, -75.788395 39.700286999999996 0 0, -75.788395 39.700030999999996 0 0, -75.7884665379611 39.6951022248818 0 0, -75.788479176698289 39.6942314495293 0 0, -75.788658 39.681911 0 0, -75.7886469376544 39.681603098048292 0 0, -75.78861599999999 39.680741999999995 0 0, -75.788633391921593 39.6714120622458 0 0, -75.788655907550691 39.659333499406 0 0, -75.788658 39.658211 0 0, -75.788431434671409 39.654318127515495 0 0, -75.788430900679188 39.6543089523983 0 0, -75.7881295637419 39.6491313452212 0 0, -75.7880955854847 39.6485475267544 0 0, -75.787787176812 39.6432484121769 0 0, -75.787541702471188 39.6390306427924 0 0, -75.78754100266589 39.6390186186539 0 0, -75.787449999999993 39.637454999999996 0 0, -75.787202839355288 39.634418454936196 0 0, -75.7871896545333 39.6342564699798 0 0, -75.78689 39.630575 0 0, -75.786216419654011 39.6217124085307 0 0, -75.7854092147263 39.611091659946794 0 0, -75.7850543631961 39.606422723028494 0 0, -75.785053894501687 39.606416556210895 0 0, -75.7843181210525 39.596735662857796 0 0, -75.78384245023949 39.5904770537489 0 0, -75.783842208850487 39.590473877688893 0 0, -75.782823521373089 39.5770705606221 0 0, -75.782460041179007 39.5722880925958 0 0, -75.7824575074535 39.5722547552599 0 0, -75.780785999999992 39.550262 0 0, -75.7796634388864 39.5365036098544 0 0, -75.7795851648761 39.5355442639815 0 0, -75.7795846104508 39.5355374688062 0 0, -75.7795181992453 39.5347235164389 0 0, -75.7762226834811 39.494332849895 0 0, -75.775129622280389 39.4809360180705 0 0, -75.7738556911832 39.465322399495996 0 0, -75.7722345420767 39.4454531900426 0 0, -75.769830558762592 39.415989368484894 0 0, -75.7666931907181 39.377537 0 0, -75.766667 39.377216 0 0, -75.765847374248 39.3671747047822 0 0, -75.7643882360415 39.349298695569395 0 0, -75.7604691694169 39.3012859228405 0 0, -75.7601316135502 39.297150501153595 0 0, -75.760104352373 39.2968165224723 0 0, -75.75 39.297474 0 0, -75.746048 39.297531 0 0, -75.714901 39.299366 0 0, -75.685188 39.297089 0 0, -75.683117 39.294578 0 0, -75.681384999999992 39.293205 0 0, -75.680261 39.292496 0 0, -75.678041999999991 39.292477 0 0, -75.6752 39.290498 0 0, -75.673327 39.291027 0 0, -75.670301999999992 39.290890999999995 0 0, -75.669276 39.291396999999996 0 0, -75.66726899999999 39.290417 0 0, -75.665810999999991 39.290566999999996 0 0, -75.660476 39.291672 0 0, -75.654461 39.291184 0 0, -75.652947 39.291948999999995 0 0, -75.65135 39.291588999999995 0 0, -75.64917899999999 39.293151 0 0, -75.647686 39.29588 0 0, -75.646293 39.29687 0 0, -75.6427 39.299107 0 0, -75.641928 39.300891 0 0, -75.640875 39.301224 0 0, -75.633937 39.301593 0 0, -75.63225 39.301327 0 0, -75.627530999999991 39.304438 0 0, -75.626132 39.30413 0 0, -75.62404699999999 39.306376 0 0, -75.623263999999992 39.308029 0 0, -75.62137899999999 39.308755 0 0, -75.619631 39.310058 0 0, -75.61605999999999 39.309734999999996 0 0, -75.614256 39.308307 0 0, -75.612008 39.308954 0 0, -75.610863 39.309276 0 0, -75.609385 39.308800999999995 0 0, -75.606597999999991 39.30809 0 0, -75.603836 39.311181999999995 0 0, -75.603445999999991 39.309094 0 0, -75.602031 39.30811 0 0, -75.599571 39.308442 0 0, -75.599218 39.309737 0 0, -75.597106 39.309554 0 0, -75.596609 39.309647 0 0, -75.594841 39.309903999999996 0 0, -75.59388899999999 39.308417 0 0, -75.592338 39.309948 0 0, -75.592056 39.311251999999996 0 0, -75.590409 39.311746 0 0, -75.58749499999999 39.311009 0 0, -75.587324999999993 39.309698999999995 0 0, -75.58476499999999 39.308644 0 0, -75.581144999999992 39.311130999999996 0 0, -75.57462 39.313434 0 0, -75.57095799999999 39.318844999999996 0 0, -75.56871599957131 39.323523001317263 0 0, -75.569820001173056 39.326576996779295 0 0, -75.569007 39.328744 0 0, -75.56480599999999 39.331936 0 0, -75.562733999999992 39.332104 0 0, -75.558843 39.333334 0 0, -75.556204999999991 39.335325 0 0, -75.555681007372513 39.33653000312443 0 0, -75.55631799999999 39.337879 0 0, -75.55833399521066 39.339230004872931 0 0, -75.557357995926381 39.341500995668405 0 0, -75.557846 39.342763999999995 0 0, -75.559981999999991 39.343466 0 0, -75.56051899792655 39.345066999353946 0 0, -75.5588 39.346548999999996 0 0, -75.557378 39.349101 0 0, -75.55619 39.348287 0 0, -75.555886 39.346743 0 0, -75.554223 39.345403999999995 0 0, -75.551599 39.345105 0 0, -75.551039996261352 39.345567994418367 0 0, -75.551096 39.349483 0 0, -75.552241999999993 39.350156999999996 0 0, -75.553840999999991 39.349938 0 0, -75.554683007400541 39.351506002990355 0 0, -75.553369 39.35301 0 0, -75.551626 39.35394 0 0, -75.549645 39.353854999999996 0 0, -75.548131 39.352920999999995 0 0, -75.54811 39.351713 0 0, -75.545216 39.350763 0 0, -75.544056 39.351363 0 0, -75.543263 39.353235999999995 0 0, -75.541586 39.354366 0 0, -75.539867 39.353887 0 0, -75.53899 39.351954 0 0, -75.535849 39.350617 0 0, -75.534483994047335 39.351388997582582 0 0, -75.53427799305544 39.353332004157252 0 0, -75.531914 39.354594999999996 0 0, -75.528696 39.353429999999996 0 0, -75.527258995814222 39.354675001898435 0 0, -75.528673 39.356781999999995 0 0, -75.52845300020698 39.358305006725651 0 0, -75.525877 39.359642 0 0, -75.523254 39.359711999999995 0 0, -75.521419999999992 39.358607 0 0, -75.519628 39.360065999999996 0 0, -75.516897 39.360988 0 0, -75.515975 39.364363 0 0, -75.51237208219473 39.365656144406771 0 0, -75.512996 39.366153 0 0, -75.515796999999992 39.378347 0 0, -75.52126299999999 39.381654 0 0, -75.521682 39.387871 0 0, -75.523583 39.391583 0 0, -75.535977 39.409383999999996 0 0, -75.538512 39.416502 0 0, -75.555889999999991 39.430351 0 0, -75.571829994645924 39.438896995945825 0 0, -75.5714550448173 39.4404895611251 0 0, -75.5709849993434 39.442485993390129 0 0, -75.573077 39.445373 0 0, -75.578914 39.44788 0 0, -75.5795930686755 39.4494326149262 0 0, -75.580185 39.450786 0 0, -75.589439 39.460812 0 0, -75.589901 39.462022 0 0, -75.592328999999992 39.467577999999996 0 0, -75.593068 39.477996 0 0, -75.593068000877849 39.47918599762091 0 0, -75.587813999749756 39.49032700194055 0 0, -75.587729 39.495369 0 0, -75.587729 39.4957407450199 0 0, -75.587728998315711 39.4963530034779 0 0, -75.586554401533689 39.497688711813 0 0, -75.581140859129292 39.5038448006784 0 0, -75.576436 39.509195 0 0, -75.574502999999993 39.512516999999995 0 0, -75.5728617838115 39.5160342206675 0 0, -75.572364001474554 39.5171009984447 0 0, -75.570362 39.527223 0 0, -75.569418 39.539124 0 0, -75.569358999999992 39.540589 0 0, -75.565636001056717 39.558509006016514 0 0, -75.564649 39.559922 0 0, -75.5641182880885 39.5606837276848 0 0, -75.563034004787326 39.562239998169261 0 0, -75.570782999999992 39.56728 0 0, -75.571598999999992 39.567727999999995 0 0, -75.586016 39.578448 0 0, -75.586608 39.57888 0 0, -75.58702738490949 39.5798547865464 0 0, -75.58720000000001 39.580256 0 0, -75.587744 39.580672 0 0, -75.591984 39.583248 0 0, -75.592224 39.583568 0 0, -75.597173322751 39.5877820945208 0 0, -75.598747 39.589121999999996 0 0, -75.600785536192 39.5890537256847 0 0, -75.603584 39.58896 0 0, -75.60464 39.58992 0 0, -75.611873 39.597408 0 0, -75.611905 39.597567999999995 0 0, -75.613792996204168 39.606191997215134 0 0, -75.613473001357889 39.606832002184781 0 0, -75.613476995906737 39.606860998404279 0 0, -75.6134736873228 39.606868426370596 0 0, -75.613233 39.607408 0 0, -75.611343991850447 39.610182999893205 0 0, -75.61366500749152 39.612559994452383 0 0, -75.613344994092387 39.613056004804442 0 0, -75.614273 39.61464 0 0, -75.614929004901924 39.615951994615266 0 0, -75.614065 39.61832 0 0, -75.613377 39.620287999999995 0 0, -75.613153 39.62096 0 0, -75.611969 39.621967999999995 0 0, -75.6004949488643 39.6353936845212 0 0, -75.5917467759147 39.6456298433782 0 0, -75.587147 39.651012 0 0, -75.5830124717269 39.6522635452232 0 0, -75.569037 39.656493999999995 0 0, -75.562246 39.656712 0 0, -75.5613567608041 39.6577726838033 0 0, -75.5568448905546 39.6631544390364 0 0, -75.5565726400012 39.663479179279292 0 0, -75.5537715895688 39.666820269999704 0 0, -75.5508077933438 39.6703554837718 0 0, -75.550803870881907 39.670360162481195 0 0, -75.5507962726737 39.670369225617904 0 0, -75.5349831512427 39.689231104242 0 0, -75.5319118207207 39.692894584837696 0 0, -75.52553303088601 39.7005032002623 0 0, -75.512682348589891 39.7158314838503 0 0, -75.509113 39.720089 0 0, -75.4964817737103 39.743315194477894 0 0, -75.490242999999992 39.754787 0 0, -75.4897514259047 39.755503457769095 0 0, -75.4719915820485 39.7813880156216 0 0, -75.4697455653652 39.7846615325088 0 0, -75.4690045587194 39.7857415323977 0 0, -75.468502 39.786474 0 0, -75.446497431828192 39.7963039695592 0 0, -75.4234159950776 39.806614995941658 0 0, -75.428038 39.809211999999995 0 0, -75.4339085190138 39.8117473186932 0 0, -75.4370683549011 39.8131119665163 0 0, -75.437307916589788 39.8132154267429 0 0, -75.449874383721593 39.8186425446778 0 0, -75.45374 39.820312 0 0, -75.454997184031086 39.820770300605005 0 0, -75.4598175446831 39.8225275407136 0 0, -75.4599264483802 39.822567241051004 0 0, -75.463341 39.823812 0 0, -75.463456872955192 39.8238463068355 0 0, -75.472547501842 39.826537795193694 0 0, -75.472677629082384 39.826576322336 0 0, -75.4754890471753 39.8274087068895 0 0, -75.481242 39.829111999999995 0 0, -75.481244921815687 39.8291126972119 0 0, -75.4930772205643 39.831936153535004 0 0, -75.498843 39.833312 0 0, -75.4989861331738 39.833333899718795 0 0, -75.518444 39.836310999999995 0 0, -75.5188176150883 39.836344961758094 0 0, -75.539346 39.838211 0 0, -75.5400582754622 39.838229220042 0 0, -75.5408864120625 39.838250403817796 0 0, -75.5513215785919 39.8385173359007 0 0, -75.570464 39.839006999999995 0 0, -75.5793939947411 39.8385493199286 0 0, -75.579849 39.838526 0 0, -75.5798996512343 39.8385220738603 0 0, -75.5930817368867 39.8375002881084 0 0, -75.593666 39.837455 0 0, -75.59484583814249 39.8372862097586 0 0, -75.595756 39.837156 0 0, -75.617251 39.833999 0 0, -75.634706 39.830163999999996 0 0, -75.634812797602493 39.8301357641688 0 0, -75.641517999999991 39.828362999999996 0 0, -75.662821999999991 39.821149999999996 0 0, -75.667142678086009 39.819267244337 0 0, -75.680794056787789 39.813318592285796 0 0, -75.6815568950873 39.812986181932693 0 0, -75.685991 39.811054 0 0, -75.701208 39.802606 0 0, -75.705787295543 39.7995238880071 0 0, -75.716968999999992 39.791998 0 0, -75.7193345673559 39.7901506045411 0 0, -75.7233991238184 39.7869763794942 0 0, -75.724866264384787 39.785830612575595 0 0, -75.727049 39.784126 0 0, -75.736488999999992 39.775759 0 0, -75.7393235590979 39.77292479948 0 0, -75.7393766862116 39.772871679087004 0 0, -75.744394 39.767855 0 0, -75.751436564661 39.759552050150596 0 0, -75.75306599999999 39.757630999999996 0 0, -75.7544659060403 39.7556311342282 0 0, -75.7592137517567 39.748848497490393 0 0, -75.760101611338087 39.7475801266599 0 0, -75.760346 39.747231 0 0, -75.7658791814134 39.7381059004001 0 0, -75.766058 39.737811 0 0, -75.773786 39.7222 0 0, -75.788595997316847 39.722198993930377 0 0)))'
      , ' 0 0', ''
    )
  ) as polygon
),  b as ( select to_geography('POINT(-75.677 39.708)') point)

select ST_ASWKT(point)
  , ST_ASWKT(polygon)
  , st_intersects(polygon, point) intersects 
from a, b
```

[image]

(previously the error was `100256: Error parsing Geo input`)

--

Bonus, charting with `st_simplify(p, 100)` just to see how it changes:

[image]

Comment: I was just noticing those, I have no idea how they got in there since my copy in SQL Server doesn't have them.  Thanks!